# Redirect script output and at the same time display it in realtime

Tags: shell, unix, stdout, tee

I've got a probably simple (and probably even already answered) question regarding displaying output from several scripts and at the same time writing their stout/stderr to a log file:

I have a script "my_script.sh" which itself calls another script like that:

```
./my_to_be_logged_script.sh 2>&1 | tee -a "$LOGFILE"
```

my_to_be_logged_script.sh among other operations calls a Python script and another shell script like that:

```
./my_to_be_logged_shell_subscript.sh
python "my_to_be_logged_py_subscript.py"
```

First of all, everything is logged properly to LOGFILE.

The shell script output is displayed in real-time but the console displays the output of the Python script only when the Python script has completed. Is there a way to display the Python output in real-time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python output buffering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering)

Answer (score 0):

try python -u "my_to_be_logged_py_subscript.py"